# compiling swig python3 with vc++, error LNK2019

Tags: visual-c++, linker, python-3.x, swig

i have developed a python extension module using swig. The module were first developed on linux with gnu tools and all worked fine but now i'm porting it to windows using visual c++.

The wrapper file generation ends successfully; the problem comes when i try to link the file wrapper and to generate the pyd extension module.

I use this command to link:

```
link /DEBUG /OUT:dist\Debug\_pipeit.pyd build\Debug\pipeit_wrap.obj /LIBPATH:..\Debug /LIBPATH:C:\python32\libs /DLL  "pipeit.lib" "python32.lib"
```

the linker gives this series of linkking errors:

```
1>     Creazione della libreria dist\Debug\_pipeit.lib e dell'oggetto     dist\Debug\_pipeit.exp in corso...
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno     __imp__PyInstanceMethod_New non risolto nella funzione _SWIG_PyInstanceMethod_New
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyLong_FromVoidPtr non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyObject_long
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__Py_DecRef non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyObject_repr
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyUnicodeUCS2_Concat non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyObject_repr
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyUnicodeUCS2_FromFormat non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyObject_repr
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__Py_BuildValue non risolto nella funzione __SWIG_Py_None
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyObject_IsTrue non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyObject_own
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyBool_FromLong non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyObject_own
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyArg_UnpackTuple non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyObject_own
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyType_Ready non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyObject_TypeOnce
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyObject_GenericGetAttr non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyObject_TypeOnce
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyBytes_AsStringAndSize non risolto nella funzione "char * __cdecl SWIG_Python_str_AsChar(struct _object *)" (?SWIG_Python_str_AsChar@@YAPADPAU_object@@@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyUnicodeUCS2_AsUTF8String non risolto nella funzione "char * __cdecl SWIG_Python_str_AsChar(struct _object *)" (?SWIG_Python_str_AsChar@@YAPADPAU_object@@@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString non risolto nella funzione "struct _object * __cdecl SWIG_Python_str_FromChar(char const *)" (?SWIG_Python_str_FromChar@@YAPAU_object@@PBD@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp___Py_NotImplementedStruct non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyObject_Free non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyObject_dealloc
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyObject_dealloc
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyObject_Init non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyObject_New
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyObject_Malloc non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyObject_New
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyErr_Occurred non risolto nella funzione "public: virtual double __thiscall SwigDirector_PDLElementVisitor::visitPDLLiteral(class gestface::PDLLiteral const &)" (?visitPDLLiteral@SwigDirector_PDLElementVisitor@@UAENABVPDLLiteral@gestface@@@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyObject_CallMethod non risolto nella funzione "public: virtual double __thiscall SwigDirector_PDLElementVisitor::visitPDLLiteral(class gestface::PDLLiteral const &)" (?visitPDLLiteral@SwigDirector_PDLElementVisitor@@UAENABVPDLLiteral@gestface@@@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyExc_AttributeError non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyExc_SystemError non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyExc_ValueError non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyExc_SyntaxError non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyExc_OverflowError non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyExc_ZeroDivisionError non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyExc_TypeError non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyExc_IndexError non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyExc_RuntimeError non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyExc_IOError non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyExc_MemoryError non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp___PyObject_New non risolto nella funzione _SWIG_Python_NewPointerObj
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyBaseObject_Type non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyObject_SetAttr non risolto nella funzione _SWIG_Python_NewShadowInstance
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyObject_Call non risolto nella funzione _SWIG_Python_NewShadowInstance
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyErr_SetString non risolto nella funzione "public: __thiscall Swig::DirectorException::DirectorException(struct _object *,char const *,char const *)" (??0DirectorException@Swig@@QAE@PAU_object@@PBD1@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyErr_Clear non risolto nella funzione "int __cdecl SWIG_AsVal_double(struct _object *,double *)" (?SWIG_AsVal_double@@YAHPAU_object@@PAN@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyLong_AsDouble non risolto nella funzione "int __cdecl SWIG_AsVal_double(struct _object *,double *)" (?SWIG_AsVal_double@@YAHPAU_object@@PAN@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyLong_AsLong non risolto nella funzione "int __cdecl SWIG_AsVal_double(struct _object *,double *)" (?SWIG_AsVal_double@@YAHPAU_object@@PAN@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyFloat_AsDouble non risolto nella funzione "int __cdecl SWIG_AsVal_double(struct _object *,double *)" (?SWIG_AsVal_double@@YAHPAU_object@@PAN@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyType_IsSubtype non risolto nella funzione "int __cdecl SWIG_AsVal_double(struct _object *,double *)" (?SWIG_AsVal_double@@YAHPAU_object@@PAN@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyFloat_Type non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyArg_ParseTuple non risolto nella funzione __wrap_delete_SwigPyIterator
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyObject_GetAttr non risolto nella funzione _SWIG_Python_GetSwigThis
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyExc_StopIteration non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyErr_SetObject non risolto nella funzione "void __cdecl SWIG_Python_SetErrorObj(struct _object *,struct _object *)" (?SWIG_Python_SetErrorObj@@YAXPAU_object@@0@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyExc_NotImplementedError non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyObject_Size non risolto nella funzione __wrap_SwigPyIterator_incr
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyLong_AsUnsignedLong non risolto nella funzione "int __cdecl SWIG_AsVal_unsigned_SS_long(struct _object *,unsigned long *)" (?SWIG_AsVal_unsigned_SS_long@@YAHPAU_object@@PAK@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyLong_FromLong non risolto nella funzione "struct _object * __cdecl SWIG_From_ptrdiff_t(int)" (?SWIG_From_ptrdiff_t@@YAPAU_object@@H@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyTuple_SetItem non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyClientData_New
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyTuple_New non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyClientData_New
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyObject_GetAttrString non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyClientData_New
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyObject_IsInstance non risolto nella funzione _SwigPyClientData_New
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyType_Type non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyLong_FromUnsignedLong non risolto nella funzione "struct _object * __cdecl SWIG_From_unsigned_SS_long(unsigned long)" (?SWIG_From_unsigned_SS_long@@YAPAU_object@@K@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyUnicodeUCS2_FromStringAndSize non risolto nella funzione "struct _object * __cdecl SWIG_FromCharPtrAndSize(char const *,unsigned int)" (?SWIG_FromCharPtrAndSize@@YAPAU_object@@PBDI@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PySlice_Type non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PySlice_GetIndices non risolto nella funzione "void __cdecl std_list_Sl_std_string_Sg____delitem____SWIG_1(class std::list<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > *,struct PySliceObject *)" (?std_list_Sl_std_string_Sg____delitem____SWIG_1@@YAXPAV?$list@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@PAUPySliceObject@@@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyList_New non risolto nella funzione "struct _object * __cdecl std_map_Sl_std_string_Sc_gestface_Configuration_Sg__keys(class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class gestface::Configuration,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class gestface::Configuration> > > *)" (?std_map_Sl_std_string_Sc_gestface_Configuration_Sg__keys@@YAPAU_object@@PAV?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@@std@@@2@@std@@@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyFloat_FromDouble non risolto nella funzione __catch$__wrap_Configuration_get_double_parameter$4
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyDict_SetItemString non risolto nella funzione _PyInit__pipeit
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyModule_GetDict non risolto nella funzione _PyInit__pipeit
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyModule_Create2 non risolto nella funzione _PyInit__pipeit
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyCapsule_Import non risolto nella funzione _SWIG_Python_GetModule
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyModule_AddObject non risolto nella funzione _SWIG_Python_SetModule
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyCapsule_New non risolto nella funzione _SWIG_Python_SetModule
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyImport_AddModule non risolto nella funzione _SWIG_Python_SetModule
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyCapsule_GetPointer non risolto nella funzione _SWIG_Python_DestroyModule
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyUnicode_InternFromString non risolto nella funzione _swig_varlink_repr
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno __imp__PyExc_NameError non risolto
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyDict_SetItem non risolto nella funzione "public: static struct _object * __cdecl swig::traits_from<class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class gestface::Configuration,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class gestface::Configuration> > > >::asdict(class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class gestface::Configuration,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class gestface::Configuration> > > const &)" (?asdict@?$traits_from@V?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@@std@@@2@@std@@@swig@@SAPAU_object@@ABV?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@@std@@@2@@std@@@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyDict_New non risolto nella funzione "public: static struct _object * __cdecl swig::traits_from<class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class gestface::Configuration,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class gestface::Configuration> > > >::asdict(class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class gestface::Configuration,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class gestface::Configuration> > > const &)" (?asdict@?$traits_from@V?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@@std@@@2@@std@@@swig@@SAPAU_object@@ABV?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@@std@@@2@@std@@@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PySequence_GetItem non risolto nella funzione "public: static int __cdecl swig::traits_asptr<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class gestface::Configuration> >::asptr(struct _object *,struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class gestface::Configuration> * *)" (?asptr@?$traits_asptr@U?$pair@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@@std@@@swig@@SAHPAU_object@@PAPAU?$pair@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@@std@@@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PySequence_Size non risolto nella funzione "public: static int __cdecl swig::traits_asptr<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class gestface::Configuration> >::asptr(struct _object *,struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class gestface::Configuration> * *)" (?asptr@?$traits_asptr@U?$pair@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@@std@@@swig@@SAHPAU_object@@PAPAU?$pair@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@@std@@@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PySequence_Check non risolto nella funzione "public: static int __cdecl swig::traits_asptr<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class gestface::Configuration> >::asptr(struct _object *,struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class gestface::Configuration> * *)" (?asptr@?$traits_asptr@U?$pair@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@@std@@@swig@@SAHPAU_object@@PAPAU?$pair@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@@std@@@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PySequence_Fast non risolto nella funzione "public: static int __cdecl swig::traits_asptr<class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class gestface::Configuration,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class gestface::Configuration> > > >::asptr(struct _object *,class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class gestface::Configuration,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class gestface::Configuration> > > * *)" (?asptr@?$traits_asptr@V?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@@std@@@2@@std@@@swig@@SAHPAU_object@@PAPAV?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VConfiguration@gestface@@@std@@@2@@std@@@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyErr_Format non risolto nella funzione "void __cdecl SWIG_Python_AddErrorMsg(char const *)" (?SWIG_Python_AddErrorMsg@@YAXPBD@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyObject_Str non risolto nella funzione "void __cdecl SWIG_Python_AddErrorMsg(char const *)" (?SWIG_Python_AddErrorMsg@@YAXPBD@Z)
1>pipeit_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno __imp__PyErr_Fetch non risolto nella funzione "void __cdecl SWIG_Python_AddErrorMsg(char const *)" (?SWIG_Python_AddErrorMsg@@YAXPBD@Z)
1>dist\Debug\_pipeit.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 81 esterni non risolti
1>  make: *** [_pipeit.pyd] Error 1120
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(183,5): error MSB3073: uscita dal comando "make -f wrap/python/Makefile
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(183,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" con codice 2.
```

pipeit.lib is my module.

python32.lib is located in c:\python32\libs while python3.dll is in c:\python32\DLLs.
From a dumpbin output on python3.dll it seems that all functions are correctly exported.

Any idea?

Thank you,
Luca

Comment: No ideas? maybe should i integrate the question with more information?

Answer (score 1):

> link /DEBUG [...]

Probably you are mixing debug and release libs. Also there may be problems with the 64bit version of python 3. Try to make a release build using python 3 x86.